# Spring Boot merge configuration properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've a use case where I need to bind configuration properties based on two prefixes, one of which is determined at runtime. Let's say the constant prefix is `foo` and the runtime prefix is `bar`.

Given a new instance of Java Bean class `FooBar`, the code should bind all environment variables `FOO_`, then overwrite with all environment variables `BAR_`.

There's a way to dynamically bind a prefix to a class, as I had stated in [this ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12664) (sample code shown below). However, what's missing is the merging of the results.

```
var bindable = Bindable.of(FooBar.class);
var properties = ConfigurationPropertySources.get(env);
new Binder(properties)
  .bind("prefix", bindable)
  .orElse(new FooBar());
```

**Example:**

```
public class FooBar {
    private Duration latency = Duration.ofMillis(500L);
    // other properties
    // getters, setters
}
```

If there are no environment variables `FOO_LATENCY` or `BAR_LATENCY`, `FooBar.getLatency()` is 500 ms. If only one of `FOO_LATENCY` and `BAR_LATENCY` is present, `FooBar.getLatency()` takes its value. If both `FOO_LATENCY` and `BAR_LATENCY` are present, `FooBar.getLatency()` takes the value of `BAR_LATENCY`.

Any idea how can this be done?

Comment: Opened https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/26144.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Just call `bind` again. It only assigns values that are found in the configuration properties, and last prefix bound will win, on a property-by-property basis.

*Example*

```java
class FooBar {
    private String a;
    private String b = "B";
    private String c;
    private String d;
    private String e = "E";
    // Getter, setters, and toString here
}
```

*Properties (YAML)*

```yaml
x.a: Hello
x.b: World
z.a: Goodbye
z.c: Test
```

*Test*

```java
Binder binder = Binder.get(env);
FooBar fooBar = new FooBar();
System.out.println(fooBar);
fooBar = binder.bind("x", Bindable.ofInstance(fooBar)).orElse(fooBar);
System.out.println(fooBar);
fooBar = binder.bind("y", Bindable.ofInstance(fooBar)).orElse(fooBar);
System.out.println(fooBar);
fooBar = binder.bind("z", Bindable.ofInstance(fooBar)).orElse(fooBar);
System.out.println(fooBar);
```

*Output*

```
FooBar[a=null, b=B, c=null, d=null, e=E]
FooBar[a=Hello, b=World, c=null, d=null, e=E]
FooBar[a=Hello, b=World, c=null, d=null, e=E]
FooBar[a=Goodbye, b=World, c=Test, d=null, e=E]
```

As you can see, the third binding overrides the values from the first, but only for properties that are actually configured, which is why the second binding does nothing.

I also simplified the logic to skip the use of `ConfigurationPropertySources.get()`.

Comment: Your test is wrong, since you're specifying both `foo` and `bar` at all times. Remove `bar` from properties, set `FooBar.b="blah"`, and see what you get 2nd time.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Sure it works. I've updated example to include default values.

Comment: It doesn't, I've updated my comment to point out the problem.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Ok, try now.